# SetState() called in a constructor flutter

Tags: flutter

I've tried to create a Gesture_detector that calls a future function when an icon is pressed, The widget builder containing the gesture_detector is called from the following code.

```
`class MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  File contentimage, style_image;


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Neural Style transfer'),
        ),
        body: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          children: <Widget>[
             //I am calling the builder from here.
            imagepreview_state().build_imagepreview(context, contentimage,'Content Image'),
            imagepreview_state().build_imagepreview(context, style_image,'Style Image')
          ],
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: (){
           // image = await getImage_gallery(image);
          },
          tooltip: 'Pick Image',
          child: Icon(Icons.add_a_photo),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

}
`
```

The following contains the builder.

```
    class imagepreview extends StatefulWidget {
  imagepreview_state createState() => imagepreview_state();
}

class imagepreview_state extends State<imagepreview> {
  noSuchMethod(Invocation i) => super.noSuchMethod(i);

  File image;
  final picker = ImagePicker();

  //These future functions get the images from the respective sources when an icon is pressed

  Future getImage_gallery(File _image) async {
    final pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    _image = File(pickedFile.path);
    setState(() {
      _image = File(pickedFile.path);
    });
    return _image;
  }

  Future<File> getImage_camera(File _image) async {
    final pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.camera);

    setState(() {
      _image = File(pickedFile.path);
    });

    return _image;
  }

  Widget build_imagepreview(BuildContext context, File image, String title) {
    return (Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
        child: Column(children: <Widget>[
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.push(context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyDetailPage(image)));
            },
            child: Container(
              height: 150,
              width: 150,
              child: image == null
                  ? Text('No image selected.')
                  : Column(children: <Widget>[
                      Text(title),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 5,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        height: 120.0,
                        width: 120.0,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          image: DecorationImage(
                            image: FileImage(image),
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          ),
                          shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                        ),
                      )
                    ]),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
              children: <Widget>[
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () async{
                    image = await getImage_camera(image);
                  },
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.camera_alt,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    size: 40.0,
                    semanticLabel: 'Text to announce in accessibility modes',
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 10,
                ),
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () async{
                    image = await getImage_gallery(image);

                  },
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.settings_system_daydream,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    size: 40.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ])));
  }
}
```

Question:

Is there any method where i can refresh my build without calling setstate() and react to when an icon is pressed?

Comment: widget tree is **not** re-built unless the `setState()` method is invoked so there's no other option if you want to update the build method

Comment: Why are you calling the state class (imagepreview_state)? A widget state class should always be private. You should instance the widget itself, not its state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the reason you want to avoid calling `setState()` here is that you've decided to go with your own builder function. I would suggest replacing `build_imagepreview` with the `build` function of `imagepreview_state` instead so you can call `setState()` from the `GestureDetector`. You could still pass `content_image` and `style_image` through the `image` attribute of `imagepreview_state` by creating a constructor for `imagepreview_state`. In addition, you can move `setState()` out of the async functions.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use setState() to call the build function again. The problem is you're not using the inherited Build() function. I am guessing it is because you want to pass in parameters into your imagepreview widget. A solution around this would be to pass in the parameters directly into the widget as class properties, and not to a custom build function. As a sidenote, this is technically how it should be done to properly build the widget tree, and you should not be calling methods within a state to create.

You can then create your widgets:

```
imagepreview(contentimage,'Content Image'),
imagepreview_(style_image,'Style Image')
```

You can then access these in the child by using widget.propertyName.

Make sure now to use the

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {}
```

method and then setState() should work.

If you then need to update anything in the parent widget, you can also pass in a function, including functions that call setState() in the parent.

Hope this helps!